# Highlighting a single point in oxyplot?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, oxyplot

I have an oxyplot winforms control that I'm using in a WPF project. The control takes in two lists (one for x values and one for y values), and plots a lineseries. I'm trying to get my WPF project to loop through these points one at a time and highlight (simple color change) each point the loop hits. However, I can't find a way to change just one point, only the entire series.

For instance:

```
var s1 = new LineSeries();

s1.Color = OxyColors.LightBlue;
s1.MarkerFill = OxyColors.Blue;
s1.MarkerType = OxyPlot.MarkerType.Circle;
```

This changes all the points in the lineseries to a light blue color, the line itself to blue, and the points to a circle shape.

There's no methods or properties to change a single point though.

Comment: you could use another series where you set only the single point.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. And thank you for demanding a real answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use another series where you set only the single point.